# When can you recover a connection from totally geodesic submanifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $g_{ab}$ a Riemaniann ( Lorentzian ) metric in a $n-$dimensional manifold $N$ and let $M$ be a submanifold of $N$. In general, the Levi-Civitta connection induced by the induced metric in $M$ isn't given just by restriction. This happen only when $M$ is a totally geodesic submanifold. 
My question is:

How many totally geodesic submanifolds of codimension $k$ are enough to recover the Christoffel symbols at a point in $N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very rare to have totally geodesic submanifolds of dimension $>1$. Indeed, if you have one through each $p$ for every $2$-plane in $T_pN$, then $N$ must have constant curvature.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering whether the statement in this old answer is obvious, or whether you can suggest a reference. Thank you.

Comment: @EmilioFerrucci: I do not know a reference. I wrote this as an exercise for my graduate differential geometry course some years ago. The point is first that if you have a totally geodesic surface $S$, then $R(e_1,e_2,e_1,e_\mu) = 0$ ($e_1,e_2$ orthonormal frame for $S$, $e_\mu$ normal). Next, if you assume that $\exp_p(U)$ is totally geodesic for $U$ an open subset of an arbitrary $2$-plane, then for any $X\in T_pM$, show that every vector in $X^\perp$ is an eigenvector of the symmetric map $T$ given by $Tv\cdot v = R(X,v,X,v)$. From this you can deduce constant sectional curvature.

Comment: thanks, this makes sense.